# General Question about Finding Combination Matches

Tags: r, pattern-matching, matching, string-matching

I'm very new to coding in R (please forgive me for any errors in terminology, etiquette, etc.). I've decided to start a project so that I can get a little more experience. I'm an archaeologist that studies animal bones, and in my field we have a quantitative unit called the Minimum Number of Elements (MNE). This unit is a pain to calculate manually, and I'm trying to automate the calculation. MNE is the minimum number of whole bones that could represent a collection of fragmented bones. So, I have skeletal part codes that represent certain portions of bone, and I have developed rules for finding combinations in a specific sequence. Certain combinations equal 1 MNE, etc.

Here's an example of a dataframe I have:

```
EL_S    PT
1P_L    1
HU_L    107,107,107,108,108
FE_L    103,105,108,110,103,103,108,110,105,107,103
```

The column `EL_S` represent the Skeletal Element and Side (so `FE_L` equals a Left Femur) and the column `PT` is a character vector of the part codes associated with that bone and side. For example, the combination of 103 & 105 equals 1 MNE. To be more specific, what is the best way to:

1. Assign certain values to PT combinations (However, PT 1 equals a whole bone and is 1 MNE. So, I'd have to give that a value even though it isn't a combo.)
2. Find and extract these combos (or single values) from the character vector
3. Tally their occurrence
4. Load that tally to a new "MNE" column
5. And do this all in a specified order

I certainly realize this is crazy specific ask from this community. I fully do not expect that anyone will solve all these problems for me. But if anyone has any advice on specific functions to use, etc., for any steps in this process, I would be extremely grateful. I was thinking of using stringr to combine code strings into say 103105 and then counting those matches. But I'm not so sure that is the most efficient way to do this. Again, any help here is much appreciated!

Edit for Clarification:

In a perfect world, this is what I'm hoping to create.

I start with the above example:

```
EL_S    PT
1P_L    1
HU_L    107,107,107,108,108
FE_L    103,105,108,110,103,103,108,110,105,107,103
```

I would want to find and extract PT 1 first. That part code equals 1 MNE.

```
EL_S    PT                                          MNE
1P_L                                                1
HU_L    107,107,107,108,108
FE_L    103,105,108,110,103,103,108,110,105,107,103
```

Next I want to find and extract the combo 103,105. That equals 1 MNE. In the above table, FE_L had two instances of 103,105 combinations so the MNE = 2.

```
EL_S    PT                            MNE
1P_L                                  1
HU_L    107,107,107,108,108
FE_L    108,110,103,103,108,110,107   2
```

And this would go on and on until there are no more part codes. Adding to the MNE column as specific combinations are found (or single PT values). I hope that makes sense. Apologies if anything is unclear here.

Comment: Hi Thanatocoenose (relevant name, had to Google it). My initial thought was to split the `PT` column using `tidyr::separate_rows` to make it into long format. Does that make sense in this case? Does the order of the part codes matter?

Comment: Thanks for the name compliment! The order of the part codes is generally unstructured within the dataframe. But the order in which they are found, extracted, and tallied does matter. I initially had this in long format, but I transformed it because I thought it might be easier to visually represent. And I was thinking about using stringr and assigning these character vectors onto their corresponding EL_S. But the more I thought about stringr the more I thought I might be wasting my time... and that I should just ask for help/advice. Hahaha.

Comment: I'm going edit my previous post to give a little more clarification of what I'm looking to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df` looks like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = "EL_S    PT
1P_L    1
HU_L    107,107,107,108,108
FE_L    103,105,108,110,103,103,108,110,105,107,103", header = TRUE)


  EL_S                                          PT
1 1P_L                                           1
2 HU_L                         107,107,107,108,108
3 FE_L 103,105,108,110,103,103,108,110,105,107,103
```

we can turn it into wide form and add the column you want to tally into, which is initially filled with zeros:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_wide <- df %>% 
  separate_rows("PT") %>% 
  count(EL_S, PT) %>% 
  spread(PT, n, fill = 0) %>% 
  mutate(MNE = 0)


# A tibble: 3 x 8
  EL_S    `1` `103` `105` `107` `108` `110`   MNE
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1P_L      1     0     0     0     0     0     0
2 FE_L      0     4     2     1     2     2     0
3 HU_L      0     0     0     3     2     0     0
```

I think we need to proceed iteratively (since the order in which we do things matters).
The first step in your example is part code `1`. We select the correct count-column(s), apply a minimum, add this to the tally column, and subtract this from the observations we have accounted for.

```
part_codes <- c("1")
num_mne <- apply(df_wide[part_codes], 1, FUN=min)
df_wide$MNE <- df_wide$MNE + num_mne
df_wide[part_codes] <- df_wide[part_codes] - num_mne


# A tibble: 3 x 8
  EL_S    `1` `103` `105` `107` `108` `110`   MNE
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1P_L      0     0     0     0     0     0     1
2 FE_L      0     4     2     1     2     2     0
3 HU_L      0     0     0     3     2     0     0
```

Then, we can do the same for `103,105`:

```
part_codes <- c("103", "105")
num_mne <- apply(df_wide[part_codes], 1, FUN=min)
df_wide$MNE <- df_wide$MNE + num_mne
df_wide[part_codes] <- df_wide[part_codes] - num_mne


# A tibble: 3 x 8
  EL_S    `1` `103` `105` `107` `108` `110`   MNE
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1P_L      0     0     0     0     0     0     1
2 FE_L      0     2     0     1     2     2     2
3 HU_L      0     0     0     3     2     0     0
```

Since the code is the same except for the `part_codes` variable, I think you could wrap this in a function and loop (or apply) over the part code combinations you want to process.

Does this do what you want?